# Post Issue in sending data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I am facing issue in sending data to server using axois which occured recently. I am getting null value in CustomerInfo and i could see the payload has data in browser network. Can you please let me know where i am making mistake. Any help would be appreciated.

Code:

```
 submit: function () {
    const $this = this;                 
    axios.post('/Customer/AddNewCustomer', {
        CustomerInfo: JSON.stringify(this.DataInformation)
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        location.reload();
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.error(error);   
    });
}
```

Server:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task AddNewCustomer(string CustomerInfo)
{
}
```

Comment: @Yogi , There is no errors in console. When i debug the AddNewCustomer method in controller customer is null

Comment: I would suspect that the actual payload type didn't match the expected payload type and so became replaced with null, but that kind of thing can depend on the backend which we know nothing about (framework, version, configuration, endpoint code, etc.).

Comment: Post parameter names are case-sensitive. Are you looking for `Data` or `data` in the server code?

Comment: What's the reason for `const $this = this;`? You never use `$this`.

Comment: This doesn't look like an Axios problem. Check the network tab to see what's being sent. It's more likely a problem with the server code, I'm not sure what language and framework that is.

Comment: It's .NET but not clear what version.  .NET endpoints expect primitive parameters to appear in the request URI, whereas you're sending JSON in the body.  1) you don't need to stringify on the frontend, axios automatically does that for you.  2) the endpoint parameter should be a defined Model class with properties matching the request data, not **string**.

Comment: Review how parameter binding works in .NET.  [This](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/webapi/parameter-binding-in-web-api) resource, for one, might help